# SQL statement optimization issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, union

I want to show rows where region = 'sample' as first rows in result. I mean priority must be higher than another rows and they must be at the top.

I use the SQL below for this result.

```
SELECT * FROM works Where region = 'sample' UNION Select * FROM works Where region <> 'sample'
```

Is there any optimal way to get result without UNION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Union will not guarantee order. Even if  you do it like that, there are chances not to be in the right order. So you have to do it with an order by clause.

Easy

```
select * from work order by case when region='sample' then 0 else 1 end
```

better if you have an index on region

```
select *,0 as ordb from work where region = 'sample'
union
select *,1 as ordb from work where region <> 'sample'
order by ordb
```

Comment: +1 for observing that the UNION in the question does not guarantee the order required.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an `order`:

```
SELECT * FROM works
order by case when region = 'sample' then 1 else 2 end
```

If you want your data also to be ordered by another column, you can add it at the end like this:

```
order by case when region = 'sample' then 1 else 2 end, othercolumn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM works 

order by case region when 'sample' then 1 else 2 end;
```

may be it will help you...